# how to get object value using eval() on a string

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm playing with wikipedia json, so… I have this object:

```
Object {query: Object}
query: Object
    pages: Object
        869994: Object
            ns: 0
            pageid: 869994
            revisions: Array[1]
            title // <- I need you baby
```

retrieved with an id (in this case, 869994). Now I want to retrieve the title, so i should use

```
    $.getJSON(myIdUrl, function(data) {

    var obj = 'data.query.pages.' + id + '.title';

    console.log(obj); // it prints data.query.pages.869994.title should be right..

    var title = eval(obj); // now I want to assign obj title value to my variable

    // something else…      
});
```

I get an error, "SyntaxError: Unexpected number '.869994' "…

I think I misunderstood the eval() function, or just making the wrong path to retrieve obj data…

suggestions? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var obj = 'data.query.pages.' + id + '.title';
```

to this:

```
var obj = 'data.query.pages["' + id + '"].title';
```

The reason is that the parser is confused; when you dereference an object it's expecting an identifier, not a literal number.

```
var x = {};
x.5 = "test"; // <- notice this seems very unnatural
```